# How do I get the unformatted cell value in an Excel source in SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis

I've got a problem with importing an SQL spreadsheet into SSIS.
The spreadsheet has values in its columns, such as `40.09`, however the cell has a custom format on it so it displays as `$40` and this is the value that SSIS attempts to bring in.

I can't change the source spreadsheet as it is supplied by a vendor, and the purpose of this package is to automate the import of this spreadsheet. I tried changing the data type of the external and output columns of the Excel source to currency however at runtime, I received an error about not being able to convert due to loss of precision. The annoying thing is it correctly picked up another column as currency (which I'm guessing is because this column has values within the first 8 rows?).

Any advice on how to get the unformatted value?

Comment: Have you tried the IMEX=1 solution? See [link](https://www.concentra.co.uk/blog/why-ssis-always-gets-excel-data-types-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it)

Comment: I did with no luck unfortunately

Comment: And presumably you cannot save it as .csv??

Comment: No,  this will be pulling in a file provided by the vendor so we have no control of how the file comes in and the point is to automate the process so no manual steps